# If $Ker(T)=\{0\}$, so does $AX=B$ have a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have to prove if it's true or not that, given $T$ a linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, such that
$$[T]_{\beta}=A$$
where $\beta$ is the canonical basis, then, if $Ker(T)=\{0\}$, the system
$$AX=B$$
has solutions and they are infinite.

I could prove that $AX=B$ has a solution iff $B\in Im(T)$. What I could think about was: since $Ker(T)=\{0\}$ then
$$\dim(Ker(T))=0$$
and therefore
$$\dim(Im(T))=n$$
but I really don't know if this is the right way and if so, how can it help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dim(\operatorname{im} T) = n$ means that $\operatorname{im} T = \mathbb R^n$, which in turn implies that $B \in \operatorname{im} T$.

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $ker T = {0}$ this implies that $T$ is bijective. If $T$ is bijective that would imply that $Ax=b$ has only a single solution. Thus the statement that there is an infinite number of solutions is false.